# Rails 3: "uninitialized constant Formtastic::FormBuilder" error after deploying app on production server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, production, formtastic

I am trying to deploy my Rails3.0 application on production server. There was many troubles before, but all of them solved. And now I have another.

There is a passenger error page's text:

**Error message:**
uninitialized constant Formtastic::FormBuilder

**Exception class:**
NameError

**Backtrace:**

0   /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3.0/gems/client_side_validations-3.1.0/lib/client_side_validations/formtastic.rb    20  in `'

1   /home/ubuntu/projects/questroad/config/initializers/client_side_validations.rb  4   in `'
2   /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3.0/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/engine.rb 201 in`block (2 levels) in '

3   /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3.0/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/engine.rb 200 in `each'

...

Google search results not helped me, and now I am here.

**UPD:**
Also if i try to run WEBrick server there was the same error.

**UPD:**
I try to comment "gem 'client_side_validation'" line in Gemfile, and error is disappeared. But now i cant use this gem.

Comment: Do you have the `formtastic` gem installed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I experience the same issue but not on the production, i got this error in the development after doing a:

```
bundle update
```

and then try to run my rspecs.

It seems that bundle update, installed client_side_validations 3.1.0 which seems to make problems ( ... not sure why, I don't have the time to analyze it atm), however using a fixed version in the Gemfile solved it:

```
gem 'client_side_validations', '3.0.5'
```

hope it helps!

Comment: Yes, it helps! I find this solution yesterday, but stackoverflow not allow me to answer myself question. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 3):

This happening because you have Formtastic 1.x installed. The 3.1.x version of ClientSideValidations expects Formtastic 2.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have formtastic gem installed.

Also run this on production machine

```
bundle install --deployment
```

As this will install all the gems to location which passenger can find. Sometimes, it happens that passenger can't find the gem paths.

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunatelly it isn't help me.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you have follow this process but i recomand you to wrap your passenger with your gemset and start with RVM for independent passenger mode

```
rvm wrapper ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3.0 passenger
```

and for start for example like this :

```
rvm_path=$HOME/.rvm/ $HOME/.rvm/bin/rvm-shell '1.9.2-p180@rails3.0' -c \
    'cd /<your app PATH>/current/ && bundle exec passenger start -a 127.0.0.1 -p 3000 -d
```

Comment: Sorry, but i'm dont understand how can I use it. And I haven't rvm-shell in $HOME/.rvm/bin. Also I use passenger as nginx module.

Comment: It's strange ? Please verify your rvm installation. Other way you must call directly $HOME/.rvm/bin/bootup_passenger or $HOME/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails3.0/bin/passenger